# Current in RC circuit using Thevenin's equivalents or Kirchoff's laws

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

Say we have a DC circuit with multiple capacitors and resistors (and batteries) in it. All capacitors are assumed to be initially uncharged. Suppose we're interested in finding the current through different resistors or capacitors as a function of time. How can we proceed?

I was thinking about using two different techniques that should work:

a) **Kirchoff's Laws**: Applying Kirchoff's current and loop laws in the circuit at any moment when the charges in the capacitors are $q_1$, $q_2$, ... and so on should work and give us enough equations to work on. However, as it turns out, this method is rather long and it is not always feasible to solve all the equations by hand.

b) **Thevenin's/Norton's Equivalents**: I was thinking about reducing the whole circuit about, say the $i$th capacitor using an equivalent battery and an equivalent resistance to find the current through this capacitor, then working on another capacitor and so on and so forth. What I don't get, however, is whether or not we will require an equivalent capacitor in the reduced Thevenin circuit. I know how to work with this approach if we have 1 capacitor, but I can't extend it for many capacitors.
             For an example, say we have a circuit with 2 resistances (each parallel with one capacitor) and 2 capacitors, then to find the current as a function of time about one of the capacitors, how will we go about reducing the circuit via Thevenin's equivalents? Can an idea of Thevenin equivalents work for capacitors?

If there is any other technique that you can think of that leads to an answer, please enlighten me with it. Also I would like to know how the two techniques I listed above can lead me to the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Thevenin's/Norton's Equivalents**: I was thinking about reducing the whole circuit about, say the ith capacitor using an equivalent battery and an equivalent resistance to find the current through this capacitor, then working on another capacitor and so on and so forth.

OK. But to reduce the circuit to an equivalent, you will be using Kirchhoff's laws, either explicitly (using nodal or mesh analysis) or implicitly (using series and parallel combinations). Ultimately this method will be equivalent to the "Kirchhoff's Laws" method.

> What I don't get, however, is whether or not we will require an equivalent capacitor in the reduced Thevenin circuit.

If you want to reproduce the dynamic voltage during a transient event, then you need to include the other capacitors somehow.

One way to do this would be to reproduce every passive element (resistor or capacitor) with an impedance in the Laplace domain. Then you can combine the capacitors into the Thevenin equivalent circuit the same way you do the resistors.

> I know how to work with this approach if we have 1 capacitor, but I can't extend it for many capacitors.

One thing you could do is represent the entire resistor network as an N-port network, with one port for each capacitor, and one for the voltage source. That will give you a (dependent) Thevenin (or Norton) source driving each capacitor, in response to the input on the port with the voltage source.

> Can an idea of Thevenin equivalents work for capacitors?

Yes. In the Laplace domain it's straightforward to treat capacitors in a very similar way to how you treat resistors in DC steady-state circuits.

Comment: I'm new to this terminology, can you explain what you mean by the 'Laplace domain'? So how can we find the equivalent capacitance for the reduced circuit? I assume it is by treating resistors and batteries as ideal wires and finding equivalent resistance across leads of the given capacitor, similar to how we find a Thevenin's equivalent resistance?

Comment: @Monster, it's the same as any method for using Laplace transform to solve differential equations. If it isn't part of your toolkit yet, you'll need to study a bit to get it. You won't necessarily get an equivalent resistance and capacitance, but rather an equivalent impedance that encapsulates the effects of both resistors and capacitors.

Comment: Thanks @The Photon, but how can we find the equivalent capacitance for the reduced circuit? I assume it is by treating resistors and batteries as ideal wires and finding equivalent resistance across leads of the given capacitor, similar to how we find a Thevenin's equivalent resistance?

Comment: I don't think that will work. Just find the equivalent impedance, and then take the capacitive part of that (but there's some possibility, I think, that you'd end up with a negative number).